# Datatables break when have more than 8 <th></th>

Tags: php, jquery, datatable

i am trying to apply datatables on my web, but it seems too complex for me.
This is the template i want to use in datatables:
Link: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/modal.html

[image]

It's ok when i add just 8  as example, but when i add more than 8 it will break everything. This is an example when i add more than 8 th
[image]

Do you know how to fix that or what is the error here? please help.I did import everything like in the example and it works well until i try to add more th.
This is the thing i get when i just add 8 th
[image]
 This is my code to add data in:

```
$stt= 1;
$sql= "SELECT * from fixed ORDER BY sta ASC, level ASC";
//thuc hien cau lenh voi bien conn lay tu file connection.php
$query= mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
<tr>
    <th scope="row"><?php echo $stt++?></th>
    <td><?php echo $data["ten_sp"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["ngay_sx"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["ma_sp"]?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["vitrilapdat"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["chungloai"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["nhom"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["d_an"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["nhasx"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["mieuta"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["loi"] ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php
        if($data["level"] == 1){
            echo '<p style="color: red;">Khẩn cấp</p>';
        }else if($data["level"] == 2){
            echo '<p style="color: #00b300;">Quan trọng</p>';
        } else if($data["level"] == 3){
            echo '<p style="color: #0000cc;">Cần lưu ý</p>';
        }
                    ?>  
    </td></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["mieutaloi"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["nguoikhacphuc"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["thoigian"] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data["chitiet"] ?></td>
    <td><a href="prod_fixed_editinfo.php?id=<?php echo $data["id"]?>" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" role="button">
        <?php 
        if($data["sta"] == 1){

                echo "Un-read";
                }else{
                    echo "Read";
                    } ?></a></td>

    <td><a href="prod_fixed_delete.php?id=<?php echo $data["id"]?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Xóa</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you have two closing `</td>`

Comment: where is the td i should close

Comment: *This is my code to add data in:* And how does the original code looks like to display the data as you want to?

Comment: it's just HTML code.

Comment: i try to add data from my database so i used php, while the original code just use html

Answer (score 0):

Answering from the comments.  You have two closing `</td>`.

```
<td>
    <?php
    if($data["level"] == 1){
        echo '<p style="color: red;">Khẩn cấp</p>';
    }else if($data["level"] == 2){
        echo '<p style="color: #00b300;">Quan trọng</p>';
    } else if($data["level"] == 3){
        echo '<p style="color: #0000cc;">Cần lưu ý</p>';
    }
                ?>  
</td></td> <!---two closing-->
```

Comment: i did fix that but i think it's not the error because nothing change when i fix that.